# Hello world. What is the difference and which is correct?

Tags: c++

I`ve seen 2 versions of writing the "Hello, world!" and they are slightly different. The question is: which is right?

In VS community machine application :

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

Siddhartha Rao "С++ 1 hour a day" (2017) :

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
  std::cout « "Hello World!" « std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The 2nd is definitely wrong. (Typographic `«` is not a valid operator in C++). Beside of this, the `return 0;` is optional in `main()`. ([cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function): _4) The body of the main function does not need to contain the return statement: if control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;._)

Comment: Both of them will seemingly do the same thing, so both of them are right. You won't find the actual differences particularly interesting until you've been studying C++ for, oh, I'd say a year. So, you have plenty of time to learn a bunch of other stuff, first...

Comment: Another difference is here: [std::endl](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl). A flush is forced. Useless in most codes.

Comment: `std::endl` is almost always unnecessary. You'll see lots of code here that wastes time with it. You don't need the extra work that it does; `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker Some platforms flush when they see `\n` which is why it might seem useless. On my machine, if I use `\n` instead of every `std::endl` I won't see any output until the program finishes.

Comment: @Offtkp -- the behavior you're describing does not conform to the C standard. stdout is ordinarily line-buffered (i.e., flushes on each newline); it can also be fully buffered (which is what you describe), but **only if** "the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device". C11, 7.21.3. So using `std::endl` instead of `'\n'` is at best redundant, but when you redirect standard output to a file you'll get horrible performance because of all the unnecessary flushes.

Comment: @Offtkp -- also, note that I said it's "almost always unnecessary", not that it's "useless".

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
}
```

This is absolutely correct. The `main()` function is a special case in that you do not *have* to return any value from it; if you reach the end of `main()` without a `return` a return value of `0` is assumed.

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
 {
  std::cout « "Hello World!" « std::endl;
  return 0;
  }
```

First off, this is badly (inconsistently) indented.

Having a space between the function name and the `(` of the parameter list is uncommon, but legal.

It also uses `'«'` (`'\xab'`) instead of `<<`, which might be a typo by you -- if it isn't, that is a syntax errror as `'«'` is not understood by C++.

It is using `std::endl` instead of `\n`. This is a more difficult case.

Writing `std::endl` to an `ostream` does *two* things -- write a newline, and flush the output buffer. Whereas writing `"\n"` is only *guaranteed* to write the newline; whether it flushes the buffer depends on the buffering policy of the stream.

Output streams can be *unbuffered* (every byte is written immediately), *line buffered* (buffer is flushed at every written newline or when full), or fully buffered (buffer is flushed if full or flushed explicitly).

Output streams are line-buffered by default *unless* the implementation can assert that the output is *not* an interactive device... which excludes your terminal (which *is* an interactive device).

Hence, whether you write `std::endl` or `"\n"` does not make a difference... except where it does. In this specific case, where you are exiting the program just after the `std::cout`, it does *not* make a difference -- *any* output stream will be flushed before the program exits anyway.

The `return 0;` is optional, as I said before. It does not hurt having it there, and personally I prefer writing it out just as to not rely on anything "specific" at that point and not to confuse readers who do not know about the implicit `return 0` for `main()`. Your mileage may vary.

---

Side note on `main()`: In **C**, a function declared with empty parameter list could be called with *any number* of arguments. This is a leftover from the ancient K&R style. If you want to make sure a function *can only* be called *without* arguments, in C, you have to declare it with `( void )` as parameter list, i.e. `int main( void )`. This is recommended practice.

In **C++**, `int main()` and `int main( void )` are the same thing, and  writing out that `void` is uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

There is just no need for `return 0` for `main()`, unless you want to end the program before control reaches the end. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        if (i < 10) i++;
        else return 0; // Ending program before control reaches the end

        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }
    // But at the end of control, return 0 is not necessary
}
```